# Laravel sending no-cache header

Tags: caching, laravel, laravel-4

I'm having trouble with Laravel 4. Somehow the header

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Is always being sent in the response on all pages within my site. I can't find where or how to change it.

[image: Cache-Control: no-cache]

Since this is affecting all my controllers where I'm presenting a view with `View::Make` I would really like a way to change this globally.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an example of a controller you want to have another `Cache-Control` header. Also what value do you want instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use Cache, you can change its behavior in your "Response" object (returned by a controller method in this example) :

```
public function myControllerMethod() {
    $response = Response::make('something');
    $response->setLastModified(new DateTime("now"));
    $response->setExpires(new DateTime("tomorrow"));
    return $response;
}
```

It works in my environnement, I hope it will help.

**EDIT:**

If you want to set it globally, you can try this (in `app/start/` directory):

```
App::after(function($request, $response) {
    $response->setLastModified(new DateTime("now"));
    $response->setExpires(new DateTime("tomorrow"));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but since this affects all my controlles (not just a single one) - is there anyway I can set the header globally? I use View::make to present my views.

Answer (score 0):

To help someone else trying to find the answer for Laravel 5.4, this would be:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DateTime;

class MyController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    return response('my content here')
              ->setLastModified(new DateTime("now"))
              ->setExpires(new DateTime("tomorrow"));
   }
}
```

See also: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses for more information on getting different content (templates etc) into a response call.